# Collect Visual Studio IntelliSense errors and dump them to text file via script?

Tags: c++, intellisense

IntelliSense shows errors in the output window and I want to dump these errors into a file without copying and pasting (in other words, via the command line or by way of a script).

How can this be done?

Comment: Experience tells me that most IntelliSense errors will show up in the build output as errors if you try to build it, but that's not guaranteed. I'm not sure there is a way to get all IntelliSense errors. May I ask why you need this?

Answer (score 0):

Build log with IntelliSense errors and warning is being written by default, if you build your project with Visual Studio. You can find this log in *ProjectName*/*ConfigurationName*/*ProjectName*.txt

Visual Studio build log options: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-view-save-and-configure-build-log-files?view=vs-2019).

How to set up logging, when building from command line with MSBuild: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/obtaining-build-logs-with-msbuild?view=vs-2019).
.